# Different highlights for radio buttons

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button

I am trying to make a form with some radio buttons, and I found how to highlight a radio button like a button. For when its selected. But the questions are of type yes/no and the yes and no need to be highlighted in different ways.

And sadly I'm not sure how to do that using CSS. This is what I did:

```css
input:checked+span {
  background-color: #0a5499;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6 quetionBottomPadding">

    <label class="UWlabel"><input class="hiddenRadioButton " type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="greyLabel">YES</span></label>
    <label class="UWlabel"><input class="hiddenRadioButton " type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="greyLabel">NO</span></label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Asdadsadadadsadadadadsad</div>
</div>
```

I'm sadly not experienced enough with CSS selectors, so I'm not sure what I should add or how should I change the HTML for the functionality to be possible.

Comment: Im trying to highlight the < yes > radio button one way. And the < no > radio button another way. When clicked of course

Comment: Easy solution with jQuery. Do you want me to give it a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your radio buttons an ID and use the ID in the CSS to target each button differently:

```css
#yes:checked+span {
  background-color: #0a5499;
  color: #fff;
}

#no:checked+span {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6 quetionBottomPadding">

    <label class="UWlabel"><input id="yes" class="hiddenRadioButton " type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="greyLabel">YES</span></label>
    <label class="UWlabel"><input id="no" class="hiddenRadioButton " type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="greyLabel">NO</span></label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Asdadsadadadsadadadadsad</div>
</div>
```

If you have many yes/no questions and you want them to be highlighted all in the same way, then use classes instead of IDs:

```css
.yes:checked+span {
  background-color: #0a5499;
  color: #fff;
}

.no:checked+span {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6 quetionBottomPadding">

    <label class="UWlabel"><input class="hiddenRadioButton yes" type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="greyLabel">YES</span></label>
    <label class="UWlabel"><input class="hiddenRadioButton no" type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="greyLabel">NO</span></label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Asdadsadadadsadadadadsad</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im trying to highlight the span. I thought that was evident from the CSS. Sry for the confusion.

Comment: Ye sry about that. That was my bad, I needed to be more clear and specific. But the answer that was given by @RacilHilan works fine.